# Python argparse select a list from choices

Tags: python, argparse

How do you use argparse to provide a list of arguments from a group of choices.  For example, lets say I want something like:

```
python sample.py --p1 ['a','b'] --p2 ['x','y']
```

Where `p1` can only be any or all from list of `'a', 'b', 'c'` and `p2` can only be any or all from list of `'x', 'y', 'z'`

Comment: Argparse follows the POSUX standard. That means that argument names with more than one character (e.g. `p1`) use double dashes (`--`). `-p1` is short for `-p -1`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices

Comment: Choices only support picking 1 from the choice right? I need to be able to select one or many of the choices

Comment: You can use `nargs` to accept more than one string per flag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a way to get the behavior you want, but with a different syntax than what you present.  You have to specify each choice with a unique parameter name/value pair.  If that's ok, then the following works:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='game.py')
parser.add_argument('--p1', choices=['a', 'b', 'c'], action='append')
args = parser.parse_args(['--p1', 'a', '--p1', 'b'])
print(args)
```

Result:

```
Namespace(p1=['a', 'b'])
```

but this fails appropriately:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='game.py')
parser.add_argument('--p1', choices=['a', 'b', 'c'], action='append')
args = parser.parse_args(['--p1', 'a', '--p1', 'b', '--p1', 'x'])
print(args)
```

Result:

```
usage: game.py [-h] [--p1 {a,b,c}]
game.py: error: argument --p1: invalid choice: 'x' (choose from 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

I can find nothing in the docs that suggests that ArgumentParser will take a list of valid values as a parameter value, which is what your version would require.

Comment: Yea I guess this is the best I could do, without doing additional code.  Like I could use nargs but will need additional code to check the values if its a valid option.  Thank you very much for looking into it.  This definitely helps and will make the code cleaner

Comment: With `nargs` each string is tested against the `choices`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `nargs` with `choices`:

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: p.add_argument('-a',nargs='+', choices=['x','y','z'])
Out[3]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-a'], dest='a', nargs='+', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=['x', 'y', 'z'], help=None, metavar=None)

In [4]: p.parse_args('-a x y z x x'.split())
Out[4]: Namespace(a=['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'x'])

In [5]: p.parse_args('-a x y z w x'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-a {x,y,z} [{x,y,z} ...]]
ipython3: error: argument -a: invalid choice: 'w' (choose from 'x', 'y', 'z')
```